# custom scroll bar is not showing on iOS safari and chrome browser

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, safari, scrollbar

How am I going to enable my custom scroll in any iOS browser, my custom scroll is working on every android browsers but not on iPhone. I searched on google for the solution, didn't get any solution. I searched everywhere.

My current style I am using is given below.

```css
.custom-slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 4px;
}

.custom-slider::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 0 40px;
}

.custom-slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - scrollbars on overflow:auto divs are gone. Nothing I try brings them back, and all demos I find also show no scrollbars.

Comment: same issue here